# Where is \scope defined in the TikZ source code?

Tags: tikz-pgf, sourcecode

The control sequence `\scope` appears several times in the TikZ scource code, for instance in the following line in the definition of the `\tikz@lib@graph@parser@` macro inside the file `<tex installation directory>/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/graphs/tikzlibrariesgraphs.code.tex`:

```
\scope[graphs/.cd,@graph drawing setup/.try,@operators=,every graph/.try,#1]%
```

I can't find where it is defined.

I have `grep`ed the entire `pgf` directory tree for `\def\scope` (`grep -rF "\def\scope" pgf`) and nothing came up.

I did the same with `\let\scope` and only two relevant results appeared, inside the macros `\tikz@installcommands` and `\tikz@uninstallcommands` (both in the file `frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex`). But these macros appear to only be related to `tikzpicture`s, and, more importantly, they seem to already assume that the `\scope` control sequence is defined somewhere else:

```
\let\tikz@origscope=\scope

...

\let\scope=\tikz@origscope
```

So where is this control sequence defined?

Comment: `\scope` is not a macro but an environment in TeX format `\scope` and `\endscope`.

Comment: @percusse: I see. Thanks. Where is it defined?

Comment: grep for `\tikz@@scope@env`

Comment: @percusse: I did, but I still don't get it. Is it like TeX boolean variables, where you declare one control sequence `\ifcond`, and get two further control sequences `\condtrue` and `\condfalse` at no further cost? So if I define the macro `\tikz@@scope@env`, is the control sequence `\scope` defined automatically by TeX or by the TikZ engine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the setup of TikZ environment `\tikz@installcommands` is invoked.

```
%
% Main TikZ Environment
%

\def\tikzpicture{%
  \begingroup%
    \tikz@startup@env%
    \pgfutil@ifnextchar[\tikz@picture{\tikz@picture[]}}%}
\def\tikz@picture[#1]{%
  \pgfpicture%
  \let\tikz@atbegin@picture=\pgfutil@empty%
  \let\tikz@atend@picture=\pgfutil@empty%
  \let\tikz@transform=\relax%
  \def\tikz@time{.5}%
  \tikz@installcommands% <==============================This line
  \scope[every picture,#1]%
  \iftikz@handle@active@code%
    \tikz@switchoff@shorthands%
  \fi%
  \expandafter\tikz@atbegin@picture%
  \tikz@lib@scope@check%
}
```

This in turn has the following structure

```
%
% Install the abbreviated commands
%
\def\tikz@installcommands{%
  \let\tikz@origscope=\scope% <======== If scope is not yet defined, becomes undefined
  \let\tikz@origscoped=\scoped%
  \let\tikz@origendscope=\endscope%
  .....
  %
  \let\scope=\tikz@scope@env%<======== This is the actual definition
  \let\scoped=\tikz@scoped%
  \let\endscope=\endtikz@scope@env%
  \let\startscope=\scope%
  \let\stopscope=\endscope%
  \let\path=\tikz@command@path%
  \let\againpath=\tikz@command@againpath%
  %
  ......
}
```

Comment: OK, thanks. Now I get it. Two things threw me off. Firstly the fact that `\scope` might be undefined in the beginning of the `\tikz@installcommands` macro, but I realize now that in TeX it is not an error to use a name that has not yet been defined. Secondly, I mistook `\tikzpicture` for the handler for `pics` (chapter 18 in the manual), so I thought that the `\tikz@installcommands` macro is not even called when no pic is mentioned on the path.

Comment: @EvanAad Any LaTeX environment `someenv` is implemented as `\someenv` and `\endsomeenv`. (This is not Ti*k*Z specific - just how environments always work.)